# How to filter with a foreign key count in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a country with many hotels, how can i get all countries which have hotels? I mean a filter using count on my foreign key model?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# migration
class AddCounterCacheToCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  add_column :countries, :hotel_count, :integer, :default => 0
end

# models
class Country
  has_many :hotels
  scope :with_hotels, where('hotel_count > 0')
end

class Hotel
  belongs_to :country, :counter_cache => true
end

# controller
def index
  @countries = Country.with_hotels.all
end
```

And that's about all there is to it.

Comment: Is counter cache the best solution?

Comment: Alternately you could use joins to not return any countries without their associated hotels, but that's not as performant, and you don't have the convenience of being able to query a country object for the number of hotels it has without an additional DB query.